# Where is the 'Windows draw method' option in 2.82?

Tags: customization, performance

I started using a stylus but Blender is lagging pretty hard in 2D animation when drawing (sluggish, stuck). I looked up for advice and many suggested to reduce the number of allocated threads in the render settings, or change the 'Windows draw method' to 'Full'; these can be found easily in earlier versions, but it seems they've taken it out or moved/replaced it in this version. Where can they be found? Are they no longer available?